# Can lemon plant survive?

Tags: plant-health, citrus, lemons, outdoor

This lemon plant has always had trouble growing. Just today I noticed that the pot has earthworms, so I was thinking of moving it to another pot.

But before transplanting it, I thought I’d share pictures of the plant.

I scraped a little off the plant... As you can see, it starts green then changes to white as it reaches the roots.

Literally speaking, there’s green in the plant until it reaches the roots. Then there’s no more green.

What can I do or is this plant as good as dead?

Also, we live in the Caribbean so it receives very strong sunlight.
[image]
[[image]][[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvQMB.jpg)[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that it doesn't have any active roots, just the remains of a root system.

Earthworms don't eat plant roots, but if you have soil full of earthworms it may have other pests such as nematodes that do cause root damage.

I would try repotting it in a new pot (not an old pot that you have sort-of cleaned somehow) and new sterile compost, and hope it recovers. The reason for that advice is some of your earlier questions about "recycling" compost or using garden soil. That tree needs to be in the plant equivalent of a hospital intensive care unit until it starts to recover!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But why does the plant only have green over the roots? Are the roots not supposed to have green?

Comment: No, the roots are not supposed to be green.