# Is lemon plant dead?

Tags: plant-health, indoors, plant-recommendations, citrus, lemons

I bought this lemon plant about 1 year ago, and placed it in my rooftop, where it received very harsh sun. The plant's never been super healthy, but Lately it's been looking worse. I replanted it to a clean pot with fresh potting soil, and moved it to my balcony, where it gets more shade.

Still, I've noticed it hasn't improved. It looks like it's dying. I'm including pictures.

What can the issue be? We're in the Caribbean.

[image]
[image][image][image]
[image]

Comment: Is it the same plant as https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/49773/25758

Comment: Yes, it's the same one. Now it's in fresh potting soil in a new pot.